# If a coin is tossed 4 times and we get Head all the time then what is probability of getting exactly 3 heads?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

How to find Probability in this question? It gives different answer based on context.

**Scenario 1:**

Answer = 1

because we are getting Heads always. So probability of getting any number of Head such as be it 1, 2 , 3 or 4 it will be equal to 1.

**Scenario 2 :**

Answer = 0

because None of the times we got *exactly 3 Head* , so it should be 0.

Comment: "because we are getting Heads always" so how does this imply that we're getting exactly *three* heads in *four* tries? It would imply that we're getting exactly four heads in four tries.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer In question(source) it's not mentioned that we are trying four tries. Its ambiguous. it has just mentioned that find the probability of getting exactly 3 heads.

we may or may not do 4 tries, but previous history is we got 4 head on 4 toss all the time.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer if we are always getting head, then the probability of getting any no of head (< 5) should be 1.

Comment: I feel like this is a translation issue, because I have a feeling I understand what you mean, but I'm still not fully sure. Is this question from an English textbook?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is conditional probability, although the wording is a bit strange. Usually we have wording like "given that" or "conditioned on" or "on the condition that". Your problem says: "and we get heads all the time" but to me this is acceptable way to state a condition.

If we assume that this is conditional probability then the answer is indeed 0.

$$
P(exactly\ three\ heads\ |\ all\ heads)=\frac{P((HHHT\ or\ HHTH\ or\ HTHH\ or\ THHH)\cap\ HHHH)}{P(HHHH)}=\frac{0}{P(HHHH)}=0
$$